# ни одна из перегрузок ReadLine не принимает 1 аргументов

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int n;
            Console.ReadLine(n);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

почему пишет ошибку: ни одна из перегрузок ReadLine(n); не принимает 1 аргументов?

Comment: Почему вы поставили тэг `visual studio`? Вопрос-то по языку, в не по среде

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine` не может принимать ни одного аргумента. То есть уберите `n`.

*Пример использования*

```
String s;
s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}", s);
```

Comment: @Denis Спасибо!

Comment: @ryslandeveloper не за что) Советую в следующий раз пользоваться MSDN если возникает проблема с использонием функций. Там все подробно описано и даже с примерами.

Comment: понял, буду использовать msdn.

Answer (score 1):

Это наоборот работает.

```
n = Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine())
```

[Теория](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Практика](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

Еще пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n;

    // Проверка на корректность ввода с кла-вы.
    if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Не могу преобразовать введённое значение");
    }
    else        
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }


    Console.ReadLine();
}
```